# UITableView doesn't display the cell correctly when inserting in the first row with animations

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

My app has an UITableViewController as the root controller and a modal view to add a row to this table. I am using CoreData, so I get the data from a NSFetchedResultsController. Anyway, the problem is in the manage of the UITableView.

Each insertion makes TableView add a new cell. Everything works fine except if the cell is added in the first row. In this case its content is not displayed. The cell is blank displayed. If I tap in the cell or I scroll the table in a way the cell must be reloaded it does show its content.

I am using animations so I do [tableView beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpdates] as Apple docs said, instead of [tableView reloadData]. If I do [tableView reloadData] all works fine.

I have checked it and same code is runned for every row. It is a problem about the way the cells are displayed.

I think the problem is about "theory" of animations in TableViews and you won't probably need it, but there is the relevant code in my UITableViewController:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   Customer *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.textLabel.text = managedObject.name;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

   return cell;
}


#pragma mark - FetchedResultsController delegate


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
   [self.tableView endUpdates];
   // [self.tableView reloadData]; this make all works OK but without animations
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Did u debug the code by placing a breakpoint at the case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: and try to log the newIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

In your `switch` statement for each type of change, why not add:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

You will have to vary that code slightly depending on the type of change, but this would eliminate the need for `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Comment: Well, @colby, thanks you but I am inserting the row when tapping the button which displays the modal view for adjusting the name of the new object, so I had to put this line when coming back from modal view and there there are more problems. So, I know there are different solutions, but I don't want to change too much code because I'm sure it is a silly problem about the begin/endUpdates mechanism. I am not doing anything strange, only using this mechanism. It must works! :)